# Changing values in a distribution to match another

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, average, means

this is my first question here.

I have a distribution of prices, let's say 10,000 values. I also have reference prices for all these 10,000 values. I want to change the values of my distribution in order to match the distribution of reference prices. For example my prices have an average of 200 coins, and the reference distribution's average is 150 coins.

The first option I tried was multiplying every price by an average factor corresponding to the percentage difference of the two averages. In the example, multiply all my 10,000 values by 0.75 would give me a new average of 150 coins.

That worked ok, but I have a further restriction that prevents me to using this option, which is:

**The prices in my distribution that are below the reference prices can vary, but no too much.**

One alternative I think could work is using a Min Max Scaler, but I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: Maybe you can try to minimize the $KL$-divergence of your data from a reference distribution? This question is not really easy to answer as it's ill-defined.

Comment: @PC1 how could I define it better? What information is missing that could help answering this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not too much"? Is there a quantitative way to provide some measure?

Comment: Let's say the prices that are below reference shouldn't go down more than 5%. The idea is that they don't move further away from reference. They could move closer (which would mean increasing them), but that's not ideal either.

Comment: Then just minimize the distance between your price and its reference below 5%... I don't know if that is helpful but the way the question is asked then it will be one possible solution.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching

Comment: Make each price equal to reference price?